# How should an inline function on a Kotlin class be imported

Tags: kotlin, mockk

There is a kotlin file in a project dependency jar (called, for example, `KotlinClass`) with an inline function

```
package io.pack

inline fun <T> every(){
    ///does stuff
}
```

If I import it into a Java class as a static:

```
import static io.pack.KotlinClass.every;
```

The import is recognised.

If I import it into a Kotlin class:

```
import io.pack.every
```

or (this ought not to work anyway, but tried for completeness) as

```
import io.pack.KotlinClass.every
```

It is not recognised.

(Note: If I create my own Kotlin file with an inline function, then that can be imported into a Kotlin class with no problem. The problem is when importing from a specific project dependency.)

What might be stopping the import of this function into a kotlin class?

Comment: One thing that could break using top-level functions from dependencies is the `*.kotlin_module` file not packaged correctly into the library artifact. You can check that in the JAR, these files should be placed as `META-INF/*.kotlin_module`. If they are missing, the compiler might not be able to see top-level declarations in the library.

Comment: You can try rmb on function, and then copy reference. What is copied then?

Comment: RMB/copy reference on the function in the decompiled .class file is `io.mockk.MockKKt#every`

Comment: META-INF/*.kotlin_module in the jar does contain the name of the kotlin file (in the jar) where the functions are defined

Answer (score 2):

It works for me. I create a Kotlin module with a file called `TopLevelStandalone.kt`:

```
package io.pack

inline fun every(){
    print("Inline")
}

fun normalFun() {
    print("Normal")
}
```

The jar this project builds into contains the class file, and a `META-INF/top-level-standalone.kotlin_module` containing:

> io.packTopLevelStandaloneKt

I then create another Kotline module, manually adding the jar to its dependencies. I'm now able to call `every` or `normalFun`:

```
import io.pack.every
import io.pack.normalFun

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    every()
    normalFun()
}
```

Comment: Thanks: the specific library is `io.mockk`. The dependent jar, (in gradle: `testCompile group: 'io.mockk', name: 'mockk', version: '1.7.15'`) is in my classpath and _does_ contain a `META-INF/mockk.kotlin_module` file but `import io.mockk.every` (the function I need) doesn't work when by all accounts it should (note, I _can_ import it as a static into a Java class)

Comment: For me it recognizes the import, but gives this error "Cannot access class 'io.mockk.MockKStubScope'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies" at where `every` is called. Are you getting that?  It's strange because I actually can't find class `io.mockk.MockKStubScope` anywhere in the jar. It is in the source tree though.

Comment: I also have mockk-dsl-jvm-1.7.15.jar, mockk-agent-1.7.15.jar  and 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect', version: '1.2.40' on my classpath.